# What is the function of "but" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> Who should I meet there but Nancy?

Is that *but* the same as "Excuse me, but could you tell me the way to the station?" or "I have nothing but this one"?

Comment: It's the Negative Polarity _but_ that means _except_; in this sentence it's [triggered](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) by the _Wh_-question.

Comment: ...(OP's examples 1 & 3): whereas that in sentence 2 is a sentence connector - sub-category redirection from pragmatic marker (conversation opener/politeness) to matrix sentence. It isn't really the usual coordinator incarnation of 'but' (men are from Mars but women are from Venus) as it doesn't connect 'balanced' components - try sticking 'and' between "Excuse me" and "could you tell me the way to the station?". Its usage here is old-fashioned.

Answer (score 6):

In this context, it means *other than*.